# how to convert df character columns inside a list to an specific date format?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, date

Suppose the next df with character date columns inside a list:

```
df<- data.frame(dates=c("2021-12-31 UTC", "2021-12-27 UTC", "2021-12-26 UTC", NA),
                another_column_with_dates=c("2021-11-21 UTC", 
                                                 "2021-12-12", "2021-11-01 UTC", NA))

list_of_df <- list(df=df)
```

Then I got a function that removes "UTC" and also whitespaces, then it converts the
dates into an specific format: `"%d/%m/%Y`:

```
convert_columns_to_date <- function(x){
   
   if(is.na(x)){
     
     return(NA)
   }
   
   else if(!is.na(x)){
   # remove white-spaces and extra strings
   x<- trimws(gsub("UTC", "", x))
   
   # date format: %d/%m/%Y
   x<- format(as.Date(x), "%d/%m/%Y")
   
   return(x)
  
   
   }
   
  else {
    return(NA)
  }
   
   
 }
```

The function works well with a single input, say `convert_columns_to_date("2021-11-01 UTC")` returns the right format `"01/11/2021"`.

However when the function is applied over all columns in the df inside a list:

```
 
 date_columns_input <- c('dates', 'another_column_with_dates')
 

 for(i in 1:length(list_of_df[["df"]][date_columns_input])){
   
   
   list_of_df[["df"]][i]<- convert_columns_to_date(list_of_df["df"][i])
   
 }
```

The next error arises:

> Error in charToDate(x) :
> character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Why is this error happening? And is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) lapply** Use format_vec as shown and then lapply over the ix columns within df.  Note that as.Date removes junk at the end already and it is usually better not to overwrite objects so that it is easy to re-run without regenerating the input.  ix should be specified as a vector of column numbers or names.

```
ix <- 1:2
format_vec <- function(x) format(as.Date(x), format = "%d/%m/%Y")
L <- list_of_df
L$df[ix] <- lapply(L$df[ix], format_vec)
L
```

giving:

```
$df
       dates another_column_with_dates
1 31/12/2021                21/11/2021
2 27/12/2021                12/12/2021
3 26/12/2021                01/11/2021
4       <NA>                      <NA>
```

**2) loop** If you prefer to use a loop then:

```
ix <- 1:2
L <- list_of_df
for(i in ix) L$df[[i]]<- format_vec(L$df[[i]])
```

**3) dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)

L <- list_of_df
L$df <- L$df %>% mutate(across(1:2, format_vec))
```

**4) collapse**

```
library(collapse)

L <- list_of_df
L$df <- ftransformv(L$df, 1:2, format_vec)
```

Comment: Very simple and elegant! thanks for your help!, do you know which one is more efficient if  a  `for-loop` or `lapply`?

Comment: Typically lapply is preferred but if there are a small number of columns it is likely about the same.  You can use the microbenchmark package (or a few other similar packages) to actually time them.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, using `lubridate` and `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

list_of_df$df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ ymd(.x) %>% format("%d/%m/%Y")))

#>        dates another_column_with_dates
#> 1 31/12/2021                21/11/2021
#> 2 27/12/2021                12/12/2021
#> 3 26/12/2021                01/11/2021
#> 4       <NA>                      <NA>
```